# List custom post type in another custom post type like categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 2 custom post types plugin in wordpress admin

```
1 = Team
2 = Player
```

I just wanted to display all players in team custom post type same way like categories or taxonomies display.

Screen short attached

[image]

[image]

Comment: check this :- http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/

Comment: i don't want to list post meta, i want to link custom post type from 1 to another custom post type but display like categories dropdown or checkbox

Comment: You have to add meta box and need to save into the post meta table. And in meta box, you can list your players like categories